# case statement in Where clause issue

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I have quite a Query to write.
I have a File called FG500 which has a field called UTXT(Certification number). The key(Not Unique) for the file is Model Number(MODL).The file can have multiple rows with the model numbers. It has also create date(CRDT), create time(CRTM), change date(CHDT), Change time(CHTM)

I need to pull latest EU Certification Number(UTXT) based on Create Date& Time / Change Date& Time. That is, if the change date/Time is not 0, then pull the latest of that.. Else check the create date and pull the latest record from that.

I will have to use a case but not sure how. Any help is highly appreciated.
Sample Data:

```
Model Number    L12G4AGAEA    L12G4AGAEA
UTXT            (Blank)       E4*2002/24*0458
Create date     07/30/12      03/16/12
Create Time     08:32:22      08:32:22
Change Date     07/31/12      03/17/12
Change Time     08:32:22      08:32:22
```

Expected result would be a Blank as the highest change date/Time is the first record. Had the change date been blank, then I would go ahead with the create date/Time

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Do we assume this is for `db2`? (flavours of `sql` differ by dbms.) What is the relevance of `rpgle` to this question?

Comment: Yes , this is for DB2..

Comment: to format you sample data use a buttom hat looks like this `{}` in the toolbar - basically all it requires is an indent of 4 chars on each row. Don't use quote which does NOT provide a non-proportional font result

Comment: trying to add the table data , but not able to format.. Basically I have a MOdel number, UTXT, and the 2 date and 2 time columns

Comment: I have formatted the table (twice now) please leave it indented by at least 4 spaces on each row. *the quote format inserts a space + greater than symbol + space on the left of each line* and is not suited to a table of data

Comment: OK, assuming you will eventually figure out how to format the data correctly, please answer my other questions. is this for DB2? what is the relevance of RPGLE?

Comment: Yes. It is for DB2.. Eventually I would need to put this in a stored Procedure..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will assist. I built the table from your first set of tabular data, and the query demonstrates use of `ROW_NUMBER()` to arrive at the "latest" row for each modelnumber. I have used MS SQL Server from this example as the query syntax for DB2 is similar.

This might not be a complete answer, and as I don't have access to DB2 I'm not able to demonstrate how to combine the date and time columns which really should be done.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/939a3/4)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ModelNumber] varchar(10), [UTXT] varchar(15), [CREATEdate] datetime, [CREATEtime] varchar(8), [CHANGEdate] datetime, [CHANGEtime] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ModelNumber], [UTXT], [CREATEdate], [CREATEtime], [CHANGEdate], [CHANGEtime])
VALUES
    ('L12G4AGAEA', NULL, '2012-07-30 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-07-31 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-03-16 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-03-17 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-07-11 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-07-12 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', NULL, '2012-07-25 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-07-26 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-07-11 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-07-12 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-05-22 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-05-23 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-08-03 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-08-03 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-05-22 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-05-23 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-05-15 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-05-16 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-07-20 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-07-21 00:00:00', '08:32:22'),
    ('L12G4AGAEA', 'E4*2002/24*0458', '2012-05-11 00:00:00', '08:32:22', '2012-05-14 00:00:00', '08:32:22')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
    *
from (
      select
          *
          , row_number() over(partition by ModelNumber 
                             order by coalesce(CHANGEdate,CREATEdate) DESC) rn
      from table1
      ) d
where rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/939a3/4/0)**:

```
| ModelNumber |            UTXT |           CREATEdate | CREATEtime |           CHANGEdate | CHANGEtime | rn |
|-------------|-----------------|----------------------|------------|----------------------|------------|----|
|  L12G4AGAEA | E4*2002/24*0458 | 2012-08-03T00:00:00Z |   08:32:22 | 2012-08-03T00:00:00Z |   08:32:22 |  1 |
```

Comment: When presenting "sample data" use a row by row layout (`as you did initially`)  and indent each row from the left with 4 spaces. It will then be seen as a table (such as the tables seen above).

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is the final query I used:  Select COALESCE(( SELECT UTXT FROM FG500F WHERE MODL =          
'L12G4AGAEA' and UTxT <> ' ' ORDER BY CHGDTE desc, CHGTIM desc ,
CRTDTE desc , CRTTIM desc fetch first row only ), ' ' ) from    
sysibm/SYSDUMMY1